# what does matter do in gray-matter in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import matter from 'gray-matter';

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts');

//

...
...
...

//

export function getPostData(id) {
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');

    // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents);

    // Combine the data with the id
    return {
        id,
        ...matterResult.data,
    };
}
```

What does matter do in gray-matter in node js?

I am trying dynamic routing in Next.js, please explain the use of the matter() function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gray-matter) of the package.

You will see an example listend there:

> Converts a string with front-matter, like this:

```
---
title: Hello
slug: home
---
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

> Into an object like this:

```js
{
  content: '<h1>Hello world!</h1>',
  data: { 
    title: 'Hello', 
    slug: 'home' 
  }
}
```

[image]